# If I remove objects from S3 will they still stay in CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I'm removing objects like this:

```
  Get-S3Object -BucketName "abilitest-user-staging" -KeyPrefix "content/bundles"
```

But what will happen to the copies of these objects that were previously sent to CloudFront? Will they stay there for ever?

Answer (score 2):

Objects in cloudfront may be removed at any point, either because their expiry period has been reached (depending on the caching headers the object was served with) or just because cloudfront decided it wasn't worth keeping the copy around.

In addition it's not a simple in cloudfront / out of cloudfront situation: there are many edge locations (50+) and each of those caches the object independently: some locations may never have cached the object in the first place.

Comment: Is this even something I should bother about as I just have a few new CSS files that appear once a week and the old ones are then not used / needed.

Comment: If this is just an asset cache I wouldn't bother. S3 cost for not deleting would be marginal.

Comment: If you are using cloudfront to distribute assets. Its best to use either a query string to bust the cache or change the file name in some way for each release. That way the user should never get a stale file. You could also do an invalidation, but its not instant (takes 15-60 minutes).